# Mysql update query over 10 million records

Tags: mysql

I've got to update a field in a table (250 000 records) with the value of a field from another table (10 000 000 records) based on the email...

I've tried:
**UPDATE table1 t1, table2 t2
SET t1.country = t2.country
WHERE t1.email = t2.email**

But I got a "Query is being executed" forever.

What query should I use?

Thanks

Comment: is this a one time thing? or are you going to do this over and over, like maybe a nightly thing?

Comment: yes, this is a one time thing

Comment: i'd write a small application doing it slowly, line by line, and updating the user by printing out how far it's gone, so that a supervisor can check that it's still running.

Answer (score 2):

This would be a good opportunity to employ a `JOIN`.

```
UPDATE table1 as t1
JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.email = t2.email
SET t1.country = t2.country
```

It will still take a while for your query to process, but it should reduce the time by a significant amount.

Comment: Leo, I was missing the `as t1` on the `UPDATE` portion. Dan kindly fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see an obvious error in your query (and the database would yield an error in that case). So the problem we're looking at is to speed up the execution of your update. Is one of your two email fields indexed? If not, could you add an index and try again? E.g. ALTER TABLE table2 ADD INDEX(email)

Comment: I'm also curious about the performance.  I'm not very familiar with MySQL specifically, but I'd like to see the equivalent of explain plan/execution path and the cost, use of index, and so forth.

Comment: Performance tuning is quite tricky. It depend on your hardware, system load, etc. Picking up the "small batch" from above: you could try   UPDATE table1 t1, table2 t2 SET t1.country = t2.country WHERE t1.email = t2.email LIMIT 10

Comment: This will only update 10 records. Verify the results. If it works, you'll just have to wait until your query is finished.